# Почему не могу присвоить primary key не id полю?

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть вот така таблица

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         serial            not null,
    chat_id    bigint            not null   primary key,
    username   varchar(255),
    full_name  varchar(255)

);
```

Я хочу присвоить полю chat_id prymary key, но когда запускаю питон скрипт по созданию бд, получаю вот такую ошибку

> asyncpg.exceptions. InvalidForeignKeyError: there is no unique
> constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"

Могу ли я присвоить prymary key не id полю?

Comment: `InvalidForeignKeyError` это не создание первичного ключа. Это создание внешнего ключа. Показывайте строку скрипта, который приводит к такой проблеме

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
melkij=> CREATE TABLE users
(
    id         serial            not null,
    chat_id    bigint            not null   primary key,
    username   varchar(255),
    full_name  varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> \d users
                                             Таблица "public.users"
  Столбец  |          Тип           | Правило сортировки | Допустимость NULL |           По умолчанию            
-----------+------------------------+--------------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------
 id        | integer                |                    | not null          | nextval('users_id_seq'::regclass)
 chat_id   | bigint                 |                    | not null          | 
 username  | character varying(255) |                    |                   | 
 full_name | character varying(255) |                    |                   | 
Индексы:
    "users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (chat_id)
```

Никаких проблем.

> InvalidForeignKeyError: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"

Если всё-таки прочитать сообщение об ошибке - то будет видно что она относится к механизму foreign keys. Где-то в местах, не имеющих отношения к этому create table, вы пытаетесь создать внешний ключ. Внешний ключ обязан ссылаться на поля, являющиеся уникальными в таблице, для чего требуется существование первичного или уникального ключа по этой комбинации полей. Или по одному полю в простом и наиболее распространённом случае.

Точный текст запроса, приводящий к ошибке, вы можете достать из лога СУБД.

Comment: А как сделать 2 поля в таблице ключами?

Comment: Поясните что значит употреблённое множественное число "ключами". PK может быть только один.

Comment: я бы просто хотел, чтоб кроме первичного ключа, было еще что то, на что можно сослаться(чтоб не делать поле первичным ключом, но дать возможность ссылаться на него)

Comment: Создайте unique constraint. Для FK не нужен именно primary key, для FK нужен уникальный ключ. PK лишь частная форма уникального ограничения.